# Leftover posts in /review first answers not being reviewed

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

There are five posts currently in the /review section under the first answers tab that refuse to acknowledge I looked at them.

[image: Before Review]

For example reviewing [Facebook like button without iframe](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5781/facebook-like-button-without-iframe/20683#20683) will show as

[image: After review]

But on refreshing the page. The link returns.

I have tried editing or even placing a flag. Editing does not remove it. But it seems a flag does. Though this flag does not show up in today's stats.

[image: Stats]

*For science!*, I tried again with [Remove the Chat box from the left pane on Gmail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/102/remove-the-chat-box-from-the-left-pane-on-gmail/20323#20323)

A flag does indeed remove it from the review but not an edit.

Though the stats do not reflect the proper numbers.

[image: Stats changed but not really]

The Facebook like button question returned (most likely because I addressed the flag).

Comment: Related to my MSO post http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112892/posts-appearing-more-than-once-in-different-sections-on-the-review-page

Comment: I have reviewed the [Facebook like button without iframe](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5781/facebook-like-button-without-iframe/20683#20683) post and it has disappeared from the queue for me.

Comment: @Barry OK for *science!* review this one http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/11253/internationalization-of-a-google-form/20268#20268 . If this disappears as well then it just needs two people to get of the queue.

Comment: You're not aloooone http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111393/posts-ive-already-reviewed-show-up-in-the-review-section-again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happened cause my implementation was a bit naive.

When removing posts from the global list:

1. I removed all posts that were reviewed by 2 reviewers
2. I removed all posts you reviewed in the last 7 days.

I assumed that someone else will review all the posts you reviewed in that 7 day window.

Clearly I was wrong.

Comment: Yeah those lazy reviewers. I hate them too.

Comment: :) if I learned one thing its that if anything can go wrong, it does, and in the most horrible way